# Iterate <f:verbatim> within <ui:repeat>

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have a `@ViewScoped` bean with a `List<String>` containing plain HTML. I want to iterate over this list and output plain html:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.list}" var="html">
  <f:verbatim>#{html}</f:verbatim>
</c:forEach>
```

That snippet above works well but when the page is refreshed the bean costrunctor is recalled. This issue/bug is known: [JSTL c:forEach causes @ViewScoped bean to invoke @PostConstruct on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842401/jstl-cforeach-causes-viewscoped-bean-to-invoke-postconstruct-on-every-request)

So the suggestion is to replace `<c:forEach>` with `<ui:repeat>`.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="html">
  <f:verbatim>#{html}</f:verbatim>
</ui:repeat>
```

But that doesn't work. I have a blank page. I tried `<h:dataTable>`, `<a4j:repeat>` and `<rich:dataTable>` but nothing to do.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<h:outputText escape="false">` instead.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="html">
    <h:outputText value="#{html}" escape="false" />
</ui:repeat>
```

The `<f:verbatim>` is an old JSP-oriented tag which was intented to be able to embed plain HTML among JSF components in JSF 1.0/1.1. Without it, all the plain HTML would otherwise be rendered *before* the JSF component tree. This unintuitive behaviour was fixed in JSF 1.2 which made the tag superfluous. In Facelets it's also superfluous and in Facelets 2.0 (for JSF 2.0) it's even **deprecated**. See also the introductory text of the [tag documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/verbatim.html). Don't use it. If you want to render unescaped HTML, rather use the `<h:outputText escape="false">` as suggested in the above example. If you want to render pieces of inline HTML conditionally, rather use `<h:panelGroup>` or `<ui:fragment>` instead.

Comment: I am curious why that would make a difference? Both `f:verbatim` and `h:outputText` are components (as opposed to tag handlers), aren't they?

Comment: @meridon: In JSP, yes, but in Facelets not. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use `ViewScoped` datamodel?

in JEE5 (JSF 1.2) - could  be seam-managed   `@Factory("bean.list") List<> produceList()...` It will be view-scoped (actually page-scoped).

and in JEE6 (JSF 2.0) you can use the same pattern with CDI.

Or you can implement the same lifecycle for your list and create own solution.

Comment: please expand on this answer, it's vague.