# Parameter passing one page to another page in JSF-2.0?

Tags: java, jsf

I would like to pass a parameter from one page to another.

Each page will have a *ViewScoped* JSF Backing Bean.

Although, I try to use `<f:param>` I get the following error:
when I click `<h:commandLink>` will navigate to another page.

ERROR :

```
] Root cause of ServletException.
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to create managed bean ReservationActionBean.  The following problems were found:
     - The scope of the object referenced by expression #{param.resvDataModel}, request, is shorter than the referring managed beans (ReservationActionBean) scope of view
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:265)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    .........
```

page1.xhtml

```
<p:panelGrid style="margin-top:-1px;" id="dashboard">
    <ui:repeat value="#{DashBoard.dayList}" var="day">
        <p:row>
            <p:column style="background:#C1CDCD;width:100px;">
                <h:outputText value="#{day}" style="color:#333333;font-size:13px;">
                    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="EEE, yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <ui:repeat value="#{DashBoard.timeSlot}" var="timeSlot">
                <p:column style="background:#C1CDCD;text-align: center;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{timeSlot}" style="font-size:12px;"/>
                </p:column>
            </ui:repeat>
        </p:row>
        <ui:repeat value="#{DashBoard.resourceList}" var="res">
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{res.name}" style="font-size:12px;"/>
                </p:column>
                <ui:repeat value="#{DashBoard.getResvDataModelList(day, res)}" var="model">
                    <p:column style="background:#{model.colour};" colspan="#{model.section}">
                        <h:commandLink action="reservation" style="display:block;width:#{model.section * 50}px;height:20px;">
                            <f:param name="model" value="#{ReservationActionBean.resvDataModel}"/>
                            <!--h:outputText value="#{model.user}"rendered="#{model.resource.name == res.name ? true : false}"style="font-size:12px;"/-->
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                </ui:repeat>
            </p:row>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:panelGrid>
```

page2.xtml

```
<h:form id="reservationEntryFrom">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="resvDataModel" value="#{ReservationActionBean.resvDataModel}"/>
    </f:metadata>

    <!-- other -->

</h:form>
```

DashBoard.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "DashBoard")
@ViewScoped
public class DashBoard extends BaseBean {

    public List<ResvDataModel> getResvDataModelList(
            Date date, MeetingRoom meetingRoom) {

        // do operation
    }
}
```

ReservationActionBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="ReservationActionBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ReservationActionBean extends BaseBean  {

    @ManagedProperty("#{param.resvDataModel}")
    private ResvDataModel resvDataModel;

    //other operations
}
```

ResvDataModel.java

```
public class ResvDataModel {

    // attribute, getter and sertter

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, object);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess its cause of combination of c:foreach  and viewscope... Try to change your `ReservationActionBean` scope into Session or replace the c:foreach with ui:repeat or datatable , look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842401/jstl-cforeach-causes-viewscoped-bean-to-invoke-postconstruct-on-every-request

Comment: @Daniel, If I use `ui:repeat`, the program cannot render the output. I don't know why? I don't want to use `SessionScope` for `ReservationActionBean`.

Comment: Its a bad idea to use c:foreach with view scope...

Comment: @Daniel  `ui:repeat` does now work in `p:panelGrid` of `Primefaces`? Any way, I will try use `ui:repeat`. thanks for your supporting.

Comment: Are you using a component library?

Comment: @jahroy Primefaces 3 + JSF 2.0 used

Comment: You might need to place your `ui:repeat` inside a `p:column` inside your `p:panelGrid`

Comment: @Daniel I update full page code. Please, could you revised again?

Answer (score 5):

The `@ManagedProperty` is invoked only once during bean's construction. Imagine that the bean is in session scope and the managed property references a request scoped variable (e.g. a request parameter), then only the parameter of the very first request would be set and it would never be updated with changed request parameter values in subsequent requests *after* the session bean construction. This is considered undesired behaviour. Hence `@ManagedProperty` cannot reference something which has a narrower scope than the `@ManagedBean` itself.

In this particular case, you need `<f:viewParam>` instead. Put the following in `page2.xhtml`:

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="resvDataModel" value="#{ReservationActionBean.resvDataModel}" />
</f:metadata>
```

#### See also:

- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id/4889226#4889226)

**However**, there's another problem with this approach. You're passing non-`String` object along as a request parameter. The value would be only `com.example.ResvDataModel@hashcode` (or whatever the `toString()` method of your `ResvDataModel` class returns). This information is insufficient to reconstruct exactly the desired `ResvDataModel` instance.

You need to pass some unique identifier or action parameter value along instead of a whole complex Java object which can't be uniquely represented as a `String`.

Comment: I use `<f:viewParam>` in `page2.xhtml` as you mention. But, I still get the error. I also update my post. Could you revised again? plz,...

Comment: You forgot to remove the `@ManagedProperty`.