# JSTL c:forEach causes CDI (Seam 3) @ViewScoped bean to invoke @PostConstruct on every AJAX request using Mojarra 2.1.18+

Tags: jsf-2, jstl, cdi, view-scope, seam3

This is a followup question to some questions on stackoverflow.com:

[JSTL c:forEach causes @ViewScoped bean to invoke @PostConstruct on every request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2842401/396732)

[Why does @PostConstruct callback fire every time even though bean is @ViewScoped? JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2797231/396732)

However, we're using Mojarra 2.1.22 but our Seam 3 CDI `@ViewScoped` annotated beans always become reconstructed, that is the method annotated with `@PostConstruct` is executed and we get an new bean on every AJAX request.

All I keep hearing for a few months (it's February 2014 now) is that Mojarra 2.1.18+ has many of these bugs fixed and that the view-scoped bean should survive AJAX requests when the view is using this bean from a `<c:forEach items="#{mySeam3CdiViewScopedBean.items}" ... >`.

Here are a few bugs:

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1665

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-928 (**<- see the last comment by dwightd - I cannot confirm it!**)

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-787

https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2688

The only difference to the examples I mentioned at the top is that we're using **Seam 3.1 Faces** CDI `@ViewScoped` (+ `@Named`) and not "native" JSF `@ViewScoped` (+ `@ManagedBean`).

**Question**:

Is Seam 3 Faces (3.1 Final) the reason why it isn't working?

(How can we find out? It's not easy to translate what we have to a test case... maybe someone knows?)

---

PS: I know this is more of a forum question, but I have hopes that the people here dealing with JSF 2 but not necessarily Seam 3 (Faces) could give their feedback.

Comment: You're on Mojarra 2.1.18.  This was only fixed in JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2).  The bug will be present in your build.

Comment: We're on Mojarra 2.1.22 as mentioned. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few remarks about your questions :

- Using JSTL loop in JSF is not recommended since it's not managed in JSF lifecycle. Using facelets `ui:repeat` is the good practice
- Seam 3 is deprecated, you should avoid using it as you won't have any support if the problem comes from here.

You have two solutions (by order of preference) :

- Switch to JSF 2.2x (and CDI 1.1) which integrates native CDI compliant `@ViewScoped`. You can easily do this by using [JBoss Wildlfy 8](http://wildfly.org) or [Oracle Glassfish 4](http://wildfly.org) servers.
- If you cannot switch JSF, forget Seam Faces and switch to Deltaspike (the descendant of Seam 3 and CODI). It provides a [CDI scope for the JSF `@ViewScoped`](http://deltaspike.apache.org/jsf.html#viewscoped)

But in both case, try to get rid of JSTL in your JSF pages, it is a source of a lot of strange issues.

Comment: The problem at hand is not solvable using ´<ui:repeat>´. Nothing is being rendered in the list of menuitems (using PrimeFaces). So we're kind of stuck on ´<c:forEach>´ or we have to use some gruesome hacks.

Comment: Primefaces builds its components before `ui:repeat` happens, so there's no point on using it for that. However, instead of using for each, remind you always have the choice to **bind** the component to the managed bean. That way, you work on your component at Java side before it gets displayed on the view.

Comment: Using component bindings has the some effect on `@ViewScoped` beans: see https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492 for an even more famous bug.