# JSF 2.2: ui:repeat with dynamically generated HtmlInputText using varStatus failed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I just want to generate dynamically HtmlInputFields, in this sample i just generated 3 fields. In out.xhtml i want to render these components in with **ui:repeat** and bind them using **binding** attribute (not value!!).

The **loop.index** used with varStatus allways fails when using the binding attribute.

**exception:**

```
binding="#{loop.index}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loop' resolved to null
```

**out.xhtml:**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.htmlInputs}" varStatus="loop" var="bItem">
  <!-- THIS WORKS -->
  <h:inputText value="#{loop.index}" />
  <!-- THIS WORKS -->
  <h:inputText value="#{myBean.htmlInputs[0]}" />
  <!-- THIS WORKS ALSO -->
  <h:inputText binding="#{myBean.htmlInputs[0]}" />
  <!-- AND THIS FAILES ?? WHY ?? -->
  <h:inputText binding="#{myBean.htmlInputs[loop.index]}" /><p/> 
</ui:repeat>
```

**MyBean.java**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class BookingBean implements Serializable {
  private List<HtmlInputText> htmlInputs = new ArrayList<>();

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    HtmlInputText hInput;
    for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
      hInput = new HtmlInputText();
      hInput.setValue("item #:" + i);
      htmlInputs.add( hInput );
    }
  }

  public List<HtmlInputText> getHtmlInputs() {
    return htmlInputs;
  }

  public void setHtmlInputs(List<HtmlInputText> htmlInputs) {
    this.htmlInputs = htmlInputs;
  }
}
```

My Question is now:
How do i use bindings with dynamically generated JSF Components properly with ui:repeat in JSF 2.2 ?

Thanx

Comment: Brief story : For the sake of simplicity, you can avoid the whole mess of the nasty `List<HtmlInputText>` in the backing bean and achieve the same thing using plain simple easy-to-maintain/read/understand XHTML code.

Comment: Take a look at [jsf-dynamic-add-remove-components-in-cforeach-loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963015/jsf-dynamic-add-remove-components-in-cforeach-loop)

Comment: @DarshanPatel , thanks. nice example BUT i need to use the binding not the value attribute.

Comment: @Tiny: thanks you, but i also like simple easy-to-maintain/read/understandable java code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All binding attributes are evaluated (along with [id attribtues and taghandlers like JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)) during the [view build time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890433/whats-the-view-build-time)

the `ui:repeat` is processed during the [Render phase (later)](https://dzone.com/articles/jsf-beware-difference-between).

You shoudn't bind your inputs, you are probably interested in their values, so use a related expression (to the bean) in the Value field

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i still do not know why `<h:inputText binding="#{myBean.htmlInputs[0]}" />` works fine and  `<h:inputText binding="#{myBean.htmlInputs[loop.index]}" />` doesn't work :(

Comment: i extend my response

Comment: thanks, now i've got it. :)